# How can I redirect a web page in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect

How can I redirect www.xxx.com/hakkimda.aspx page to www.xxx.com/default.aspx?=hakkimda in Asp.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url changes, [onserver]

```
Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?foo=baar",true);
```

Url  remain Same [on server]

```
Server.Transfer("Default2.aspx?poop=baar");
```

Url changes [on client]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location="http://som_eother_location.html"
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location","www.xxx.com/default.aspx?=hakkimda");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Keep in mind if using this that this information will be stored in the caches of visitors and they will always be redirected when trying to access the site, without even contacting the server. Use "307 Temporary Redirect" if this is not wanted.

Answer (score 2):

[Response.Redirect() - msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("default.aspx", True)
```

or simplye `Response.Redirect("TeleCmslogin.aspx")`
Hope the above line of code will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the easiest way is javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href = "www.xxx.com/default.aspx?=hakkimda"; </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should type:

```
   using system.web.security;
```

then type in page load:

```
  if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
    }
```